# Pusher on Android

Tags: android, websocket, pusher

I'm trying to get Pusher working on Android. Here are my needs.

- Must support "private-" channels
- Must support secure connections
- Must be able to override the pusher/auth endpoint.

Note: I've already tried the following routes....

- loading pusher.js in a WebView and letting it fall back to SockJS
- https://github.com/pusher/pusher-phonegap-android (Does not seem to support secure connections)
- https://github.com/EmoryM/Android_Pusher/blob/master/src/com/emorym/android_pusher (Requires a private key to be pushed to the client, also not up to date)
- https://github.com/jmschultz/JavaPusherClient (Does not support private channels)

Anyone else have any luck with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pusher have a Java library: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client

There's a very simple sample application here:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-android-example

You can tell the `Pusher` instance to use an encrypted connection via `PusherOptions`. See:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pusher/client/PusherOptions.java#L24

I think this is likely to be updated to be the default, or at least reconnection will try over SSL if an unencrypted connection fails.

Comment: Just started using this project. Still some kinks to work out but its pretty good.

Comment: Hi, Have you completed work on New Java library. In my application, in iOS version, I am able to create custom authorizer and pass my request body to it. But in Android, we are still having 2 options setHeaders() and setQueryStringParameters(). How are we supposed to send request body in this method? Are there any custom authorizers? Do we have clear example on how requestbody and post works in Android pusher like iOS?

Comment: @SirajSumra I no longer work at Pusher. But the project is complete, yes.

Comment: Thanks @leggetter, Can you please look into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952078/android-pusher-request-body-implementation-in-httpauthorizer.
It would be a great help.