# Android Pusher Request Body implementation in HttpAuthorizer

Tags: android, authorization, pusher

I am new to Pusher. I had successfully implemented public channel subscription in my app. I am currently stuck at Android private channel subscription.

We are supposed to pass request body parameters in post endpoint of our server. In my iOS application, We are creating custom Authorizer to send the request body in the PusherOption. But in Android there are only 2 options to send parameters in PusherOptions like setHeaders() and setQueryStringParameters().

I have to send following body with the URL:

```
["data": ["socket_id": SOCKET_ID, "user_id": USER_ID, "channel": "private-CHANNEL_NAME"]]
```

I am currently getting exception at onAuthenticationFailure as [com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: MY ENDPOINT URL].

My current Android code is as follows:

```
public static void subscribePrivateChannel(final String channelName, final String userId, final String authKey) {
    final HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer(MY_ENDPOINT_URL);
    PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setEncrypted(true).setAuthorizer(authorizer);
    final Pusher pusher = new Pusher(Config.PUSHER_APP_KEY, options);

    pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange connectionStateChange) {
            if (connectionStateChange.getCurrentState().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("CONNECTED")) {
                String socketId = pusher.getConnection().getSocketId();
                HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                parameters.put("socket_id", socketId);
                parameters.put("channel", channelName);
                parameters.put("user_id", userId);
                authorizer.setQueryStringParameters(parameters);

                pusher.subscribePrivate(channelName, new PrivateChannelEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailure(String s, Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAuthenticationFailure() called with: s = [" + s + "], e = [" + e + "]");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String s) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSubscriptionSucceeded() called with: s = [" + s + "]");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(String s, String s1, String s2) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent() called with: s = [" + s + "], s1 = [" + s1 + "], s2 = [" + s2 + "]");
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String s, String s1, Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError() called with: s = [" + s + "], s1 = [" + s1 + "], e = [" + e + "]");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you'd like to further modify your authorizer to send the body with the request you can also just use the base interface - `com.pusher.client.Authorizer`. Would that help?

Comment: Thanks @zmarkan. Do you have any example as to how we can modify it for request body?

Answer (score 1):

You can add arbitrary request body parameters via Pusher's `UrlEncodedConnectionFactory`:

```kotlin
HttpAuthorizer(authEndpoint, UrlEncodedConnectionFactory(mapOf(
    "key1" to "value",
    "key2" to "value",
)))
```

(using `com.pusher:pusher-java-client:2.2.5`)

Frustrating that this isn't better documented/easier to find...